# Make Jquery carousel autostart instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cube

So I have a carousel that works- see it here on my jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/L4q2e35g/3/

What I need it do is an auto start and slide instead of onclick function, anyone has a quick code solution to make it work?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="grey-bordered" style="height: 300px;">
                        <div id="slideShow" class="slides-wrapper">
                            <section class="slide">
                                Section 1
                            </section>
                            <section class="slide">
                                Section 2
                            </section>
                            <section class="slide">
                                Section 3
                            </section>
                            <section class="slide">
                                Section 4
                            </section>
                            <section class="slide">
                                Section 5
                            </section>
                            <section class="slide">
                                Section 6
                            </section>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a function circle to after the s

```
function circle() {
        if (slides[currentSlide + 1]) {
            ++currentSlide;
            step();
        }else{ currentSlide = 0; step() }
    }
```

then a recursive loop function in the init and call it

```
 var  loop = function(){
                setTimeout(function(){ circle(); loop() }, 2000)
        }
 loop();
```

you can see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L4q2e35g/9/

Comment: you can also add a parameter to specify the interval in your config and pass it into your loop function... and maybe a pause state that gets changed on hover to prevent calling the step

Answer (score 2):

You can try this updated [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4q2e35g/7/)

jQuery Code changed in your fiddle:

```
function autoStart()
{
        if (currentSlide === slidesNum - 1) {
            currentSlide=0;
        }
        goNext();
}

setInterval(autoStart,3000);
```